# Problem with new Rain Shower

Tags: plumbing

Just replaced mixing valve and installed new rain head with hand held shower. Now I have a constant cold water leak.

Comment: Sounds like nothing to do with the shower head, it's the mixing valve. Need more info. What brand mixing valve was installed? Did you do it yourself or was it professionally installed? Take us through your installation steps. How about some pictures?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you might need to flush the valve.  its common to have little calcium deposits that get dislodged when you service valves.

just pull the valve and head, turn on the water and let it spray out into the tub for a moment (make sure you take out any little springs, tappets, etc. before turning on the water and keep the plug in the tub to make sure you can retrieve any that you miss).

then hold your hand over the valve body to provide enough back pressure to have the water come out the shower nipple.  once purged, just reassemble (with a little dishsoap to make sure you don't cut any seals)

this process  has a high likelihood of solving your problem (assuming all the parts are correct, installed correctly and there are no other issues)